# Add level to R Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Let's say we have a data frame/table organized like this

```
x$user1, x$user2, etc..
```

`x$usern` is a data table with attributes like `$age, $department, $sale, $price, etc.`

I would like to "push" and regroup the data frame in `x$usern` to one lower level, so that I can add other data tables below `x$usern`

Perhaps it's better with illustration : the current structure is

```
x
$user1                              $user2
$price,$age, etc.                   $price, $age, etc.
```

Target structure is

```
x
$user1                                        $user2
$data                $stat                    $data                $stat  
$price,$age, etc.    $min, $max, etc.         $price,$age, etc.    $min, $max, etc.
```

What would be the best way to achieve this. I am thinking of `lapply` and/or loop through all user, but perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a small example with actual R objects? Your text says "data frame" but your pseudocode seems to say "nested list", and I'm not sure what's really going on. If you are talking about data frames, then I'm not even sure if `user1` is a column itself or a row in a `"user"` column.

Comment: user_n is an attribute of x. x is a data frame with attributes as user_n. The data frame is retrieved  by spliting the original data table x$[user, price, age, etc.] by user, then each user will be treated for statistics, audit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good place for `lapply` (or one of its kin). Some mock data:

```
x <- list(
  user1 = data.frame(price = 11, age = 12),
  user2 = data.frame(price = 21, age = 22)
)
str(x)
# List of 2
#  $ user1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ price: num 11
#   ..$ age  : num 12
#  $ user2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ price: num 21
#   ..$ age  : num 22
```

The transformation:

```
newx <- lapply(x, function(l) {
  st <- data.frame(min = 0.9*min(l$price), max = 1.1*max(l$age))
  list(data = l, stat = st)
})
str(newx)
# List of 2
#  $ user1:List of 2
#   ..$ data:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ price: num 11
#   .. ..$ age  : num 12
#   ..$ stat:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ min: num 9.9
#   .. ..$ max: num 13.2
#  $ user2:List of 2
#   ..$ data:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ price: num 21
#   .. ..$ age  : num 22
#   ..$ stat:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ min: num 18.9
#   .. ..$ max: num 24.2
```

(Obviously, my definition of `st` would have to be tailored to your needs. Additionally, it does not strictly need to be defined within the `lapply`, but it makes sense to do it there if you already know its definition based on `x$user1$...`.)